# Visual studio code no variable suggestion

Tags: python, autocomplete, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I use vscode 1.30.2 on Mojave. I had alread installed python extension and Visual Studio IntelliCode extension. The package can autocomplete, such as

[image]

But, vscode can't recognize the type of variable and no suggestion, like
[image]
[image]

And on the Microsoft page, can show some suggestion for variable.
[image]

I had tried set "python.jediEnabled": false, not work too.
I searched on google for a long time and didn't find the answer. 
Python 2.7.15

Comment: I solved this problem by switching to jedi and uninstall the Visual Studio IntelliCode extension which is dependent on python language server.
So, may be python language server bug?

Comment: It did not work for me too, it hangs either at reloading module or if you click on go to definition it just keeps finding the references.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me with the 0.1.78 version of the language server that is available by default in the January 2019 release of the Python extension.

[image: IntelliSense for a variable containing a string]

Comment: Hi Brett, do you mind sharing your settings for user and workspace of vscode ?

Comment: https://github.com/brettcannon/dotfiles/blob/master/vscode/.config/Code/User/settings.json

Comment: Thanks you for the gist.